# Reiniciar Geolocation.watchPosition de capacitor en ionic cuando la aplicación se abre después de cerrarla por completo

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic

tengo un método que trackea la posicion de un movil con watchPoint de capacitor/geolocation

```
iniciarRastreo(){
        this.options = {
            maximumAge: 2000,
            timeout: 5000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        };
        this.watchPosId = Geolocation.watchPosition(this.options,(position, error) =>{
            this.latitud = position.coords.latitude
            this.longitud = position.coords.longitud
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e)
        })
    }
```

Este se ejecuta cuando el usuario presiona un boton y en localstorage se guarda un estado de activo. Hasta ese punto funciona correctamente, el problema viene cuando cierro la aplicacion por completo, al volverla a abrir reviso el localstorage el cual si viene con el valor de activo, de hecho si entra al metodo `iniciarRastreo()` pero `Geolocation.watchPosition` ya no devuelve la data de `position`, como si se pausara y ya no reinicia

Con este metodo lo vuelvo a llamar

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
        const ret = await Storage.get({ key: 'user-data' });
        var user = JSON.parse(ret.value);
        this.user = user.user

        if(this.user["active"] == 1){
            console.log("user activo"); //aqui si entra
            this.generales.iniciarRastreo(); //entra al metodo
        }
    }
```

Ya proble con **ionViewWillEnter**, **ionViewDidLoad** pero sigue sin reiniciarse el rastreo